# Document mode in IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, msdn

While reading topics on EDGE mode of internet explorer I encountered with two statement on same MSDN Blog
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx

> 1> Starting with IE11, edge mode is the preferred document mode;
>
> 2> Starting with IE11, document modes are deprecated and should no longer be used, except on a temporary basis

Its seems like both are conflicting each other or might be I am not able to understand it properly.
As well as I like to know why should I use edge mode.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day the IE team added compatibility mode so enterprises could upgrade and designate their legacy line of business applications to use a mode that would allow those applications to still just run.

Unfortunately compatibility mode has sort of been abused and many of those legacy applications still have not been upgraded. They also used some 'techniques' that are not exactly kosher and security safe.

Fast forward to today. The IE team has introduced Enterprise Mode, which allows enterprises to designate legacy LOB applications to use a true [IE 8 emulation mode](http://love2dev.com/#!article/The-New-Internet-Explorer-Enterprise-Mode-or-Why-You-Should-Never-Use-IE-8-Anymore) while upgrading their browser.

So why use edge? To be honest you do not actually need to use the X-UA-Compatible header or META tag. If you don't supply it IE will just use the current or latest engine to render your site. Edge mode is exactly that, the latest version. So unless you need IE 7, 8 or 9's engine to render your site you should be good. Well as long as you have a DOCTYPE ;) omitting that triggers Quirks mode.